# CSS Unpleasant white space on the right side of the screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am struggling with white space occuring on the right side of mobile devices screen when I preview my website on browser. I am using Bootstrap 4 as main CSS file. I read many posts regarding the same issue and came across the fact that the `.row` class of Bootstrap was making its div width wider that the screen size.

Here is my code:

```css
.container,
.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.container-fluid>.container>.row {
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}

[class*="col"] {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

@media (min-width:576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .container {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  [class*="col"] {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1015px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="container-fluid p-2 p-lg-0" id="hd">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-3 col-lg-2 pr-0" id="hd-1"><a href=<?php echo $lg. '/'; ?>><img src="assets/images/osi_logo_white.png" alt="OSi logo" class="img-fluid" id="hd-logo"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-lg-8 text-uppercase mb-0" id="hd-2"><a href=<?php echo $lg. '/'; ?>><?php if($lg=='fr') echo 'photographe international africain'; else echo 'international african photographer'; ?></a></div>
      <div class="col text-right align-self-stretch align-self-lg-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" id="hd-3">
        <a href="<?php echo (($lg=='fr') ? str_replace('/fr/','/en/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) : str_replace('/en/','/fr/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" class="media align-items-center">
          <span class="media-body"><?php if($lg=='fr') echo 'in english'; else echo 'en français'; ?></span>
          <img src="assets/images/<?php if($lg=='fr') echo 'uk.png'; else echo 'fr.png'; ?>" class="d-flex ml-1 ml-md-2" id="hd-lg">
        </a>
        <a href="#ft" class="d-lg-none">contacts</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I explain. I put a piece of HTML code and the piece of CSS code that is relevant to the problem. In the CSS, without the `[class*="col"]`, setting the `.row` class left and right margins fixed the problem. But The whole website shrank according to the left and right paddings of the `.col` classes of Bootstrap. So, I tried to retrieve that space by reducing those paddings (see the `[class*="col"]`) but the white space appeared again sized the same as the `[class*="col"]`.

I am stuck. If someone can help me figure out what's going on, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the way you manage the margins in your site against the default margins of Bootstrap.

As a solution I wrote my own CSS framework based on Bootstrap logic defining my own set of classes and setting my own margins.